# GitHub: Setup SSH

Tags: git, bash, ssh, github

I already setup SSH for GitHub which tutorial provided from GitHub, but there still somtething error with my Public Key `Permission Denied`, where is i miss the config?

can somebody help me?

here is the copy debug text from `ssh -v git@github.com`

```
$ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/GusDeCooL/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/GusDeCooL/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debia
n-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/GusDeCooL/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/GusDeCooL/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve gusdecool
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/GusDeCooL/.ssh/id_rsa.pub':
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please help me..
thank in advance...

Comment: Are you using cygwin or mingw? If so have you checked the permsissions of your .ssh directory? Thats usually the problem.

Comment: @Peter I Using Windows 7 with software Git

Comment: Yeah, but ssh doesn't usually run natively like that on Windows, so how are you using it? Are you running a windows cmd prompt or something that came with your Git install?

Comment: i using Git Bash, i get it from install Git. is there a solution for this?

Comment: Never Mind, i already have the solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, for security reasons ,OpenSSH denies your request to use the private key for authentication if you didn't set your permissions right for the keys files, which is 600(r+w for user and deny for rest).

Run `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa*` from Git bash, assuming you installed [Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/).

If it's not that then you most probably didn't follow through the steps of creating a key pair and importing the public key to GitHub. You might want to re-take those steps paying more attention([Generating](http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/) & [Troubleshooting](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/)).